# PHP: Return more than one ID of employees/users to a product table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table of products which each product has an employee/s that is/are responsible of. (gets an email with every update regarding this product).

These are the tables:

```
Table Products
prod_id     | prod_name |  prod_ios_id  |  prod_android_id  |   **prod_user**

Table Employee  
**emp_id**  |    emp_name       |   emp_email       |   emp_password        | emp_permissions
```

After submitting The function gets more than one ID (or an array of IDs).

What is the right way to add more than 1 ID to a table cell 'prod_user' in case ?

Comment: personally I would have "prod_user" named as "emp_id" so the joins are simpler and also it is clearer how the fields relate to each other. Having the same value in this field on multiple rows should definitely be straightforward, so long as you dont have unique values assigned to the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a 3rd table.

Table Products_Employee

prod_id, emp_id

The cell **prod_user** in Table Products can be deleted.

Comment: everytime when I want to join between 2 tables, I need a separate table for that?

Comment: Its a question of database design. It should be normalized. In your case several Rows in Table Products with the same "prod_id" can be avoided. Typically "joins" are much more faster with the 3rd table i posted for you.